# How to set cursor position UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

Is it possible to set the cursor in an UISearchBar. I know it's possible with an UITextField but I wonder if it's possible with an UISearchBar.

For a textfield it would be:

```
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:...];
```

Comment: Try this [searchBar becomeFirstResponder] in viewDidAppear;

Comment: It's not about the focus, but about setting the position of the cursor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the best solution. But it still is solution.

Here is part of UISearchBar.h:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UISearchBar : UIView { 
  @private
    UITextField            *_searchField;
```

Using KVC you can get text field from search bar:

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey: @"_searchField"];
```

And then deal with text field:

```
[textField setSelectedTextRange:...];
```

Comment: In 2021 "Access to UISearchBar's _searchField ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug". But since iOS 13 we have `searchTextField`